# Rewriting equation through division

Tags: divisibility, roots, fractions

I have an equation $$\vec E = \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_{0}} * \frac{Q}{x * \sqrt{x^2+a^2}}$$

where $\lambda = Q / 2a$

And this equation is rewritten into  $$\vec E = \frac{1}{2 \pi \epsilon_{0}} * \frac{\lambda}{x * \sqrt{(x^2/a^2)+1}}$$

I tried to divide it by $a$ but couldn't continue. I need some explanation on how it is rewritten.

Comment: Yes divide both the numerator and denominator by $a$. In denominator, take $a$ inside square root, so it would be $a^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\vec E & = \frac{1}{4 \pi \varepsilon_{0}} \frac{Q}{x \cdot \sqrt{x^2+a^2}} \qquad [Q = 2a\lambda]\\[6pt] 
& = \frac{1}{4 \pi \varepsilon_{0}} \frac{2a\lambda}{x \cdot \sqrt{x^2+a^2}} \\[6pt]
& = \frac{1}{2 \pi \varepsilon_{0}} \frac{\lambda}{\frac{x}{a} \cdot \sqrt{x^2+a^2}} \\[6pt]
& = \frac{1}{2 \pi \varepsilon_{0}} \frac{\lambda}{x \cdot \sqrt{\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{a^2}{a^2}}}
\end{align}$$